# Trouble uploading csv file to Postgres from S3 using COPY command

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, rds

I am using python script in lambda to upload a CSV file from S3 to a SQL table, which located in a Postgres RDS.

I am trying to upload data from csv file into the table like this -

```
sqlstr = "COPY mrr.{0} (\"{1}\") FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER".format(table_name, columns)  #copy from csv file to table
ss3 = boto3.client('s3')
obj = ss3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=namefile) #namefile is the csv file name
contenttotable = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
cur.copy_expert(sqlstr, contenttotable)
```

The Watchlogs are saying - `TypeError: file must be a readable file-like object for COPY FROM; a writable file-like object for COPY TO.`

> What can I do to make the script read it like a **file-like** object from the s3? (Optimally without external modules, because it is in AWS lambda).

Comment: I think the problem is that you can't actually put a file onto your lambda instance, and `COPY FROM` takes a filename, not the actual file or the contents of the file itself.  Your `contenttotable` definition is the file contents, which doesn't match up with what `COPY FROM` expects.  Maybe you can try just using `psql` from your local machine instead of a lambda instance?  Is that an option?

Comment: I want to use Lambda because it is all automated and I don't need any local machine. All the process from the s3 trigger for a new file to creating csv file on the s3 worked. This is the last part that I need to complete.

Comment: I am trying to understand what's the difference between using `with open` and reading the contents as-is (because in a local machine with the `with open` command it is working.

Answer (score 1):

When you call .read(), you read the entire "file" into memory, into one string.  So contenttotable is not a file-like object.

You could convert it back to a file-like object using StringIO, but it would likely be better to avoid reading the whole thing into memory in the first place.

Comment: So what do you suggest to do to make it more efficient?

Comment: (Considering the file is not very big and I don't really care to put the whole thing in memmory).